# why pip installs to a different location than distutils install

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, distutils

installing with `sudo python setup.py install` goes to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/git-maildiff`

while if I install using pip command `sudo pip install maildif`

it goes to different location i.e. `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

why is it like that ?

Comment: When you call `pip` you invoke a script named `pip` and you don't necessarily know what python interpreter it belongs. That depends on your `PATH` variable and if the python version you are using has pip installed.
Instead use `python -m pip install <mypackage>`. This makes sure that you invoke exactly that pip that belongs to your python interpreter. Note that in your scenario you may get an error and have to install pip first.

Comment: Right, I followed how you suggested and it seemed to be the reason but since on  my mac has two installations , How can I have only one global level of python installation , and ensure all python tools I install uses python from the one same location?

Comment: That is actually a tricky question. By setting the `PATH` variable you will always call the right tool, if you have installed it in your preferred interpreter. However if you haven't installed it but you have installed it into any of your other interpreters, you will invoke that tool corresponding to the less preferred interpreter. I can't think of a straight forward workaround for that.